# Node chaining async functions

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

Im writing a script thats supposed to convert data from my DB into another format. Essentially I get the ID's from one table and iterate through them,

```
function getAllCoinIDs(){
 db.any("SELECT coin_id FROM coins")
  .then((data) => {
    _.each(data, function(entry){
      convertToOHLC(entry.coin_id);
    })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  })
}
```

calling this function which gets all the data related to this ID from another table, groups them by timestamp and calls the next function:

```
function convertToOHLC(coin_id){
  db.any('SELECT * FROM coincap WHERE coin_id=$1 ORDER BY last_updated ASC', coin_id)
  .then((data) => {
    return _.groupBy(data, function(entry){
      return moment(entry.last_updated * 1000).utc().startOf("day").format('x');
    })
  })
  .then((data) => {
    _.each(data, function(value, key, dayData){
      parseOHLCdaily(key, value, coin_id);
    })
  })
}
```

The last function converts the data and writes it to the DB:

```
function parseOHLCdaily(timestamp, data, coin_id){
  var high_btc = _.max(data, function(o){return o.price_btc;}).price_btc;
  var low_btc = _.min(data, function(o){return o.price_btc;}).price_btc;
  var open_btc = data[0].price_btc
  var close_btc = data[data.length - 1].price_btc;

  var volume_usd = data[data.length - 1].volume_usd;
  var values = [coin_id, open_btc, high_btc, low_btc, close_btc,  volume_usd, timestamp];

  db.any("INSERT INTO ohlc_daily(coin_id, open_btc, high_btc, low_btc, close_btc, volume_usd, timestamp) SELECT $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7", values)
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  })
}
```

So the problem I'm having is, that parseOHLCdaily() is reached, (if I add a console.log it gets called as often as I would expect) but nothing is written to the DB. No error, no new records, no nothing. Really don't know whats happening here.

(Packages I'm using: pg-promise for DB queries, moment for timestamp/date operations and underscore)

Comment: `await` inside  `parseOHLCdaily` will be expecting promise that has to be resolved.Do u really need to use await for finding out min or max ?

Comment: I don't, was playing around, trying to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Where in `parseOHLCdaily` did you add the `console.log`, right before the `db.any` call? If not, one of the statements after the log might have thrown an exception. You don't seem to handle errors from the promise anywhere.

Comment: The code is just horrible in terms of the performance. You are executing `1*X*Y` queries where you should be executing just 1 query - an `INSERT` from a grouped `SELECT` that joins the list of Id-s.

Comment: I agree, performance isn't good at all. The problem I was having is the sheer amount of data I have to deal with, DB contains over 2.7GB. Im planning to push all new entries of parseOHLCdaily into an array and insert with helpers.insert, so I should end up with 1*X queries.
@Bergi I took the console.log out for some reason and forgot to add the .catch(...), since the parseOHLCdaily() will call parseOHLChourly(), having essentially the same functionality. Tried to condense the question as much as possible.